# Python Quickfix GetString() has Coredump OR Unicode Encode Error for strings >= 16 Characters

Tags: python, python-3.6, swig, python-unicode, quickfix

The following snippet of code (in a class derived from quickfix.Application) coredumps/SIGSEGV when retrieving the QuoteReqID as a String. I've played around with the size of the QuoteReqID and noticed that string fields with values < 16 characters are processed just fine, but string fields with values above that limit are not, which lead to the eventual SIGSEGV or UnicodeEncodeError. It seems like this is an issue with the SWIG layer that Quickfix uses, and specifically with python3. I just wanted to see if I am doing something wrong, or if there is already a workaround.

```
import quickfix as fix

...

def fromApp(self, message, session_id):
    msg_type = fix.MsgType()
    message.getHeader().getField(msg_type)
    if msg_type.getString() is fix.MsgType_QuoteRequest:
        quote_req_id_field = message.getField(fix.QuoteReqID())
        quote_req_id = quote_req_id_field.getString()
        print(quote_req_id)
```

I cannot seem to duplicate the conditions required for the coredump vs the UnicodeEncodeError. When the UnicodeEncodeError does occur this is what it looks like in the FIX Logs:

```
15 Characters
Original String=samplequotereqs
131=samplequotereqs

16 Characters
Original String=samplequotereqs
131=        otereqs1
```

In the second example it's not spaces preceding the 'otereqs1' but rather the a white clear vertical unicode block character which I think is U+25AF.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was accessing the fields was incorrect. This is the correct way:

```
def fromApp(self, message, session_id):
    msg_type = fix.MsgType()
    message.getHeader().getField(msg_type)
    if msg_type.getString() is fix.MsgType_QuoteRequest:
        quote_req_id = fix.QuoteReqID()
        message.getField(quote_req_id)
        print(quote_req_id.getValue())
```